# Terraform - why can't I assign a value from 1 variable to another variable

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I am trying to assign an output variable from a module to a local variable so that I can conveniently use a local variable. Is there another way ?

```
variable "vpc_id" {
  default = "${module.vpc.vpc_id}"
}
```

Error I am getting is :

```
Error: Unsupported argument

  on main.tf line 22, in variable "subnetid_private":
  22:   default = "${module.vpc.subnet_private}"

Variables may not be used here..
```

I spent good amount of time to google this but could not see any example. Am I missing something here. This is a pretty standard convenience feature of any language.

Answer (score 3):

you can replace with locals

https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/locals.html

```
locals {
  vpc_id = module.vpc.vpc_id
}
```

and later reference it as `local.vpc_id`

Answer (score 3):

I had the same thought when I first started using Terraform.

The problem is naming. A Terraform **variable** block is more like a final or constant constructor or method parameter in other languages.

From the  [Local Value](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/locals.html) documentation, it says this:

> A local value assigns a name to an expression, allowing it to be used multiple times within a module without repeating it.
>
> Comparing modules to functions in a traditional programming language: if [input variables](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/variables.html) are analogous to function arguments and [outputs values](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/outputs.html) are analogous to function return values, then local values are comparable to a function's local temporary symbols.

When you write:

```
variable "vpc_id" {
}
```

Terraform says "ah, you'd like callers of this module to be able to hand a string in called vpc_id". Definitely not what you are looking for.

For the kind of case you have, a [Local Value](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/locals.html) is what Terraform provides:

```
locals {
  vpc_id = module.vpc.vpc_id
}
```

Comment: this is a great explanation +1.

Comment: Thank you. I'm glad you found it useful @JBone :)

Answer (score -1):

In terraform 0.12, you can use variables in variables like so:

```
variable "var1" {
  type = string
  default = "this is var 1"
}

variable "var2" {
  type = string
  default = "$${variable.var1}"
}
```

output of this is:

```
$ terraform apply
Apply complete! Resources: 0 added, 0 changed, 0 destroyed.
```

Comment: That escapes the interpolation in var2. So that should output the string literal `${variable.var1}`.